# Single word for old and many-times-seen content

Tags: single-word-requests

Using `old` as a starting word, Urban Dictionary suggested:

1. Obsolete
2. Outdated
3. Archaic
4. Ancient
5. Retro
6. Passe

And I have to say that **none** of them really fit. The first two can describe software, but you don't *update* your old memes, they just get old and you rarely re-see them in a fit of nostalgia, deep inside your archives. #3 and #4 can be used in phrase describing how old is this post (e.g. `ancient as mammoth's $#!@`). But hey, that's a phrase, not a single word! #5 is about the style, not the freshness. #6 is completely about fashion (e.g. `MySpace is so passe`).
A friend of mine suggested `retoast`, but I'm unsure because I haven't really seen the usage.
Your suggestions?

Update: Very sorry to break the rules, adding an example usage now.

> Oh no, grandpa saw a pack of my business cards, and added me to his *hilarious* e-mailing list, consisting of **?????** from 2007.

Also, if any of you guys surf russian internets, you may be familiar with `баян`. I need precisely that translated. It is a common (first) comment to many posts in social networks, as re-posting happens quite often

Update 2: The small thing that I forgot to mention is that it's a noun in russian, I will sure accept the fact that there are no such, but it would be much more familiar to talk of *information units*, calling them **?????** than saying that they are `bromidic`, for example. I find `bromidic` kinda 30% suitable, but I guess I can't derive a `bromid` noun? So the speech contruction becomes longer, which is undesirable

Comment: Can you rephrase your question?  I'm unsure what you're asking.

Comment: I am voting to reopen this question as the duplicate doesn't read like it has the same context. @mekkanizer You had better edit your question to include more context. The following is the rule of this community. **Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered**. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @Rathony updated question, very sorry

Comment: @michael_timofeev I added usage example

Comment: No need to say sorry but you have to remember this rule unless you want your question to be closed so early.

Comment: @Rathony so it won't be reopened despite the update?..

Comment: You need four more votes to get it reopened. In the meantime, why not review your question and see if there is more room for improvement and review below answers? One thing for sure is your question doesn't read well.

Comment: Your question is still hopelessly unclear (and, as you can see, has already garnered two new close votes because of that).

Comment: @HotLicks how nice of you to bring the good news. I have some good news too, the other guy actually read the letters I wrote and made up a summarizing answer which explained things quite precise

Comment: Wait, if you're saying *bromidic* is the right adjective, are you sure [*bromide*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bromide_(language)) is not the right noun? As in, "Oh no, grandpa saw a pack of my business cards, and added me to his hilarious e-mailing list, consisting of **bromide** from 2007."

Comment: Translating `баян` [yielded](https://translate.google.com/?ie=UTF-8&hl=en&client=tw-ob#ru/en/%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%8F%D0%BD) `accordian`.

Comment: @jxh nice to know that, but you see, if I'm not *fully* reatrded, I of course tried translating it, but the problem is that no translator on the internet would translate Urban Dictionary to russian properly (for example). Now, the same works for russian internet slang translations. You just can't apply basic dictionary to the process

Comment: I am wondering if you are after a metaphor, or if you can explain why the relationship between *accordion* and your word request.

Comment: "A bromide is a phrase or platitude that, having been employed excessively, suggests insincerity or a lack of originality in the speaker." "a trite and unoriginal idea or remark, typically intended to soothe or placate." "a commonplace or hackneyed statement or notion". Your question isn't clear, but since you wrote that "bromidic" was close but not a noun, it seems like "bromide" could be just the thing. Seems perfectly logical to me. If you're going to be rude to people trying to help you then you might have a hard time getting help.

Comment: "Bromidic: being a bromide" You literally **can** make a noun out of "bromidic", and that noun is "bromide".

Comment: @mekkanizer [Are you sure you can't just use a dictionary?](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%8F%D0%BD) "Noun\[edit] бая́н [...] 2. (Internet slang) an old joke [...]". "Old joke" is already getting quite close to what you want, isn't it?

Comment: I still can't tell what it is you're asking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Old is (generally) an adjective in English. So all its synonyms are likely to be adjectives as well.

Going off your original post, I would absolutely use "tired", "ancient", or "antiquated", depending on what you're trying to convey. Tired suggests it's long-since gone out of fashion but is still in use, while ancient suggests it's no longer in common usage, but was at one point. Antiquated further conveys that in addition to no longer being used, it's out of fashion.

> [Tired](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tired): *hackneyed; stale: the same tired old jokes.*
>
> [Ancient](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ancient): *Of, relating to, or belonging to times long past*
>
> [Antiquated](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/antiquated): *Too old to be fashionable, suitable, or useful; outmoded.*

Paired with "memes" (as you do in the question, with "old memes") this conveys exactly what I think you're getting at:

> Oh no, grandpa saw a pack of my business cards, and added me to his hilarious e-mailing list, consisting of tired memes from 2007.

But if the one-word requirement is stronger than a requirement for common usage, "antiquities" might be sufficient. It doesn't convey the same condescending tone as tired or antiquated, but it does convey that something is dated:

> Oh no, grandpa saw a pack of my business cards, and added me to his hilarious e-mailing list, consisting of antiquities from 2007.

Alternatively "crap" would convey that it's useless, but the reader has to infer that it's also dated by the "from 2007".

You'll notice that now the sentence doesn't clearly convey *what* is being emailed. I think that's going to be somewhat tricky to avoid with a single word because the condescension stems from pairing a derogatory or dismissive adjective with a normally neutral or positive noun like meme.

Neutral:

> Grandpa sent me memes from 2007.

Condescending:

> Grandpa sent me tired memes from 2007.

---

I don't believe "repost" is what you're looking for (though it is a reasonable single-word, if that's really your priority) because it doesn't necessarily convey age or staleness. In fact repost is often used for very new content that has simply been posted previously, and therefore this post isn't original. Often when one person sees a repost others are seeing for the first time. In that sense repost actually gives grandpa some credit, because perhaps the others on the chain haven't seen what he's sending.

Comment: Nah, I just got confused while trying to explain everything to everyone. I like how you explain each of your examples, i guess I'll use tired as an adjective, and repost as a verb paired with antiquities. The problem is that english isn't native for me and I'm subconsciously trying to find the same exact word (it can mean excess re-usage and/or great age, in any combination, it just suits the case). So the solution is to just situationally use things I got from your and other answers, sometimes combining them. Thank for the time spent

Answer (score 8):

In the context you have given, it seems like you are looking for *[repost](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=repost)* (Urban Dictionary). This is the label that is often stuck on message boards and such to indicate that something has been re-posted. It can be used as a countable noun, so you could say "consisting of reposts from 2007".

Comment: Wow man, you hit it so precisely and that's a **noun**! Totally won the contest

Comment: @mekkanizer I'm glad this was good for you, but How does this have anything to do with what you described? Passé or archaic? 'Repost' just means you posted something again.

Comment: @Mitch He explained the particular context in the body of the question.

Answer (score 5):

It's not a single word unfortunately, but you could consider using [**same old thing**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+same+old+thing) that means:

> something that is extremely familiar

[Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms]

You can use **s***** in place of thing to intensify the meaning as in:

> It is the **same old s***** that I have seen so many times in other sites.

Answer (score 3):

I think ***[hackneyed](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hackneyed)*** convey the idea:

> - (of phrases, fashions, etc) used so often as to be trite, dull, and stereotyped.

Comment: Does not suit the case. Hackneyed describes some object the can *modified* in the order to make difference or be a copy. I'm asking for a word which *complains* about the fact that someone stole content on the Internet and posted is as something new despite the fact it had been seen so much times and stolen many times before by many other sources

Answer (score 3):

(entry from Concise Oxford Dictionary (tenth edition 1999))

> ***rehash,*** ● *v.* reuse (old ideas or materials) without significant change or improvement. ● *n.* an instance of rehashing.

Comment: This one implies the ability to modify content, I'm talikng of content *theft*

Answer (score 3):

The best seems to be

> worn out

Other possibilities

> recycled, reused, repackaged, dated, tired

Answer (score 3):

I think the answers here have covered a lot of the territory.

However, consider **"(old) chestnut"**, which can have a negative connotation, for example in describing a well-worn joke or story, or a neutral or positive connotation, for example in describing a familiar aphorism or saying.

> Oh no – Grandpa saw a pack of my business cards, and added me to his "hilarious" e-mail list. His messages are full of internet meme **chestnuts** from 2007.

In this sentence, the negative connotations are clear. The words "internet meme" provide clarity of context (if that is indeed the context you want), but may not be necessary, depending perhaps on your audience or further context provided elsewhere in your text.

Here are some links that you can follow to confirm the definition and suitability (note the definition that Google provides atop the search results):

- [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/old_chestnut) (*old chestnut*)

  > 1. (*idiomatic*) A well-worn story.
- [Google](https://www.google.ca/search?q=old+chestnut) (*old chestnut*)

  > 1. a joke or story that has become tedious because of its age and constant repetition.
- [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/chestnut) (*chestnut*)

  > 6. an old or stale joke, anecdote, etc.
- [Thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/joke?s=t) (*joke*; provides *chestnut*)

Here's the Wiktionary etymology information, which, along with those links, suggest that "chestnut" is very close to exactly what you're looking for:

> Originally as *chestnut*, with "old" for emphasis. Popularized US 1880s, particularly Northeast and Midwest, with various theories propounded.
>
> A commonly cited theory, viewed by the Oxford English Dictionary as "plausible" and cited by Brewer’s, is that it was coined by Boston comedic William Warren Jr., quoting from 1816 English melodrama *The Broken Sword* by William Dimond. One of the characters in the play is a boor, and when once recounting a tale mentions a cork tree, which is corrected by the character Pablo as "A chestnut. I have heard you tell the tale these 27 times." This line was then apparently quoted at a dinner party by Warren in response to a boor there, and proved popular. Note that William Warren Sr. had previously played Pablo on stage, but died in 1832, so the phrase was presumably popularized by the son, William Warren Jr.

Indeed, you've asked for the English equivalent of "баян". According to its Wiktionary entry, "баян" – literally, "accordion" – gets its figurative meaning of "old joke" from an oft-repeated and well-worn joke about an accordion (or rather, two accordions). With this ideational correspondence in their origins, "chestnut" even seems to have a similar flavor in English to "баян" in Russian, even if not the same currency on the internet.

- [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%8F%D0%BD) (баян)

  > The “old joke” sense originated from a joke (Internet meme) at http://www.anekdot.ru — "Хоронили тёщу — порвали два баяна" (when we buried my mother-in-law, we broke two accordions).

(I would even go so far as to suggest that someone should edit the Wiktionary entry for "баян" to include "chestnut", but only as I gather from my research as set out above and from reading the comments on this page. To be clear, I don't speak any Russian and I have no idea what human burial has to do with accordions, or breaking them. **Edit:** I developed a hunch that accordion wreckage was the measure of a really good Russian party. That is confirmed [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/russia/comments/2cwh5h/what_are_some_good_russian_jokes/).)

[image]

Comment: Nice bit of digging.

Comment: Thanks jxh and @hvd for pointing me in a productive direction.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two idiomatic expression you could use

> [Same s***, different day](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=same%20shit%20different%20day)

or

> [same old same old](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/same+old+same+old)

As already suggested by Rathony. No single-word comes to mind unfortunately.

Comment: The word `cliched` doesn't suite the case for the same reason described under **josh61**'s answer

Comment: @mekkanizer This answer is best used to define boring and mundane jobs. Is this helpful?

Comment: I would accept, but I can accept only one, and Rathony was first and he's kinda zealous :) I'd upvote but I have too low rep to be able to

Comment: @mekkanizer Hahaha! That's okay. I am glad I could be of help.

Comment: Well, the answer is helpful, the context comment is confusing. I have accepted the same thing from the other guy, but now you're talking about jobs... Good if it *can describe jobs too*, but in the edit I clearly stated that it's to be used in the internet, to denote continous re-usage of content or content theft. I fully agree that your answer suits the continous re-usage meaning (so now I finally upvoted) but you sure of the context?

Comment: No comma in same old same old. First instance is an adjective, second is a noun.

Comment: @mekkanizer The first one is to be used in a professional setting. The second one is universal and can be applied to everything.

Answer (score 2):

The use of the word **plagiarized** refers to content that already exists and was created by someone else, and to the fact that the content was not cited properly.

Comment: Good option BUT because it's derived from word plagiarism it's kinda wrong you know. In the Internet, this one can rather be used to shame an artist who has photoshopped other's signature on painting. But taking of other content the actual author loses value. Not all of the value, but fresheness **definitely** overtakes uniqueness

Comment: In a nutshell, won't accept cuz freshness > uniqueness, and plagiarizing describes freshness *vaguely*

Answer (score 1):

There is the [copypasta](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/copypasta) meme.

> Copypasta is internet slang for any block of text that gets copied and pasted over and over again, typically disseminated by individuals through online discussion forums and social networking sites.

[image: copy pasta image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised that no one has suggested it, but **cliche** (or clichéd "showing a lack of originality; based on frequently repeated phrases or opinions")seem appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Could you include the inteded use of the word?
I can think of

> Tired
>   bromidic
>   mundane
>   blasé

Comment: Added intended use of the wordm rethink your suggestions please, asI find none of them suitable