# Word to describe something that in itself may be admirable, but which happens too often, too predictably, to be 'good'?

Tags: single-word-requests

I know boring is one option, but it does not always
apply to the case that something maybe desirable at start, 
but once it happens too often, it becomes bad.

For example, in movies and literature, heroes always win over the evil
at last which has become too often to be good, so under that context which word could be used to describe that phenomenon?

I also want to ask can I use cliche? but the dictionary says it applies to phrase or opinion?

Comment: Answers at the duplicate show that the word _cliché_ has the broader application asked about. There have been many other related threads, for instance [Single word for old and many-times-seen content](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/296578/single-word-for-old-and-many-times-seen-content/296701#296701).

Answer (score 0):

The situation you describe about literature and movies can definitely be described as **"cliche"** , in fact that is probably what I was thinking the answer should be before I read the last line.

I would probably use a qualify to make it **so cliche** or **too cliche** or **very cliche** if you want to emphasize that it is unenjoyable.

Another word that goes along with this is [**trope**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/trope) to describe an element that appears often in an artist/writer/director's work.

Tropes easily become cliche when they become widespread.